# Ubuntu upgrade fails something about kernel?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, apt

Im running an ubuntu server version 10.04 LTS.
I did a "sudo apt-get upgrade" on my server today and it failed with the following:

```
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-318-ec2 (2.6.32-318.38) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-318-ec2
Could not find postinst hook script [update-grub].
Looked in: '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.32-318-ec2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-319-ec2 (2.6.32-319.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-319-ec2
Could not find postinst hook script [update-grub].
Looked in: '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.32-319-ec2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-34-server (2.6.32-34.77) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-34-server
Could not find postinst hook script [update-grub].
Looked in: '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.32-34-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-ec2:
 linux-image-ec2 depends on linux-image-2.6.32-319-ec2; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.32-319-ec2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-ec2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-ec2:
 linux-ec2 depends on linux-image-ec2 (= 2.6.32.319.20); however:
  Package linux-image-ec2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-ec2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-2.6.32-34-server; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.32-34-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 2.6.32.34.40); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.32-318-ec2
 linux-image-2.6.32-319-ec2
 linux-image-2.6.32-34-server
 linux-image-ec2
 linux-ec2
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This question doesn't seem appropriate for SO, perhaps ServerFault would be a better venue?  (This seems to be a question about administering an Ubuntu system rather than about programming).

Comment: sorry I wasent aware that there was a "forum" other than stackoverflow for server management :)

Comment: Please edit your post to show the output of `uname -m` and/or `lscpu`, so we know what hardware you're running on. That will determine which boot loader you should have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key error is this:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-318-ec2
Could not find postinst hook script [update-grub].
Looked in: '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'
```

All the other errors follow from that one.

It seems that dpkg wants to run update-grub, but it's not available on your host.  On my host, I have

```
$ which update-grub
/usr/sbin/update-grub
$ dpkg --search /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-pc: /usr/sbin/update-grub
$ apt-cache policy grub-pc
grub-pc:
  Installed: 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3
  Candidate: 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main amd64 Packages
```

Depending on your hardware, you might have a different one of the grub-* packages installed:

```
$ apt-file -x search '/usr/sbin/update-grub$'
grub: /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-coreboot: /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-efi-amd64: /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-efi-ia32: /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-ieee1275: /usr/sbin/update-grub
grub-pc: /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

You almost certainly have one of the above packages installed.  Use `dpkg --search /usr/sbin/update-grub` to find out which one it is, then `apt-get --reinstall install` to reinstall it.

Comment: Okay... its running on a virtualized enviroment Xen server... im not sure grup-pc is installed on any of our servers... rj@web1:~$ apt-cache policy grub-pc
grub-pc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.98-1ubuntu12
  Version table:
     1.98-1ubuntu12 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
     1.98-1ubuntu7 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.98-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages

Comment: Edited.  You may have a different grub-* package installed, depending on your hardware platform.

Comment: Ah thanks Andrew... I noticed I had removed grub-pc from this server for some reason... installing it again worked :)